# Is there any reason not to sum the kinetic and potential energy from an NPT simulation to get internal energy?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, statistical-thermodynamics, thermodynamics, cp2k

I would be very grateful for some newbie-level advice from a thermodynamics guru.

I ran NPT simulations on a particular system (in CP2K software) to get fluid densities for use in fluid dynamics applications.  Before the lockdown, a colleague mentioned that it might be interesting to use the results for describing mixing in the system thermodynamically (the system is made up of two endmember compositions).  I finally thought about it, but **can't figure out if my NPT internal energy data are meaningful** and don't want to bother my colleague, who has been sick.  I would love advice.

**I would like to know if I can simply sum my NPT ensemble-derived kinetic and potential energies to calculate internal energy**.  The reason I ask is that I came across a comment online where someone seemed to think the thermostat would interfere with the kinetic energy values.

I can't decide if this is true.  I know that energy is not conserved for NPT simulations--that energy is either added or subtracted to maintain a constant temperature.  However, it seems like that should be fine because I want the system to be at a particular temperature.  I could run another set of simulations in a different ensemble.  But that would mean a lot of extra time and computational resources, so I want to be really certain before diving in to doing more simulations.

With regard to energy not being conserved for NPT simulations, I'm wondering if it matters that my goal is to provide people with data on the thermodynamics of mixing in the system.  In other words, for the data to be useful, I need to be compare internal energies from distinct simulations run at the same pressure and temperature, but different endmember fractions (compositions)--one internal energy value by itself probably won't be useful.  I'm not sure if I'm being clear here...  The bottom line is that I can't figure out if it would be like comparing apples and oranges to compare internal energy values from different NPT simulations (and therefore cannot use my existing results to describe the thermodynamics of this system).

I have searched online for information on this, but probably don't know enough to be familiar with useful search terms.  If anyone has any hints on how to think this through, I'd be very appreciative.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I love molecular dynamics questions. The answer is yes you can add the numbers together E=U+K. The value won't be "conserved" so there really isn't any reason to plot it. E.g. usually one could plot the conserved values to see if the dynamics are stable. See this [excellent answer by Phil[(https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/644/52)

Comment: +1. Welcome to the site, and thank you for asking your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!!

Comment: @CodyAldaz and Nike Dattani, thank you both, that's very kind.  I'm glad you like molecular dynamics questions, Cody!  Someone mentioned this site when I asked a question on Chemistry and I think it's a great idea.  I ask the question, Cody, because I have noticed that no one in the published literature seems to use (or even discuss) NPT simulations for calculating internal energy.  The only thing I have seen on this topic is a sentence on a forum where someone said that the use of a thermostat in NPT means it's not valid to use NPT results to calculate internal energy. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @CodyAldaz, thank you very much for that link to Phil's answer.  Please forgive me--I'm slow on this.  Could I please confirm I understand you?  So Phil is saying that the "conserved" quantity matters for monitoring whether a time step is appropriate (or, I guess, whether a simulation is converging/reaching equilibrium).  You said that E=U+K won't be conserved for NPT.  Does that matter for me?  I.e., does it mean that the E values I calculate will be meaningless?  Or can I still use them to describe my liquid thermodynamically?  I am paranoid that my calculated E will not be meaningful.

Comment: I would also use the total energy as a metric to understand if the system is properly equilibrated. From my understanding, the kinetic energy term is mainly as a result of the temperature that the thermostat is set to - so I don't think it holds any physical meaning. However, I would think the potential energy is more meaningful - e.g. to answer questions like if a sharp fluctuation in PE at a timestep results from a specific interaction change say hydrogen bond disruption. I think it is also reasonable to compare RELATIVE AVERAGE PE since MD is a statistical mechanics approach.

Comment: @gogo, that's interesting.  Sorry, I am really struggling with this, even after your comment and the ones above.  So you think that the potential energy provides a reasonable representation of the internal energy?  If you have time, may I confirm what you mean by "relative average potential energy" (RPE)?  Do you mean that it would be reasonable to plot the RPE from all of my different simulations for the same system at distinct pressures and temperatures and call it "internal energy" for use in thermodynamic calculations/databases, for example?

Comment: Sorry for jargonizing the answer. I think potential energy is the same as internal energy and since it is a MD, you will need to average the internal energy over a certain time interval where the system is equilibrated. Let's say you have a reaction A --> B (or any state A and B). Then the relative energy, <deltaE> = <E(B)> - <E(A)>, where <> represent the time-averaged energies, should be meaningful. I don't see why you can not do the same as per your needs as a f(T,P). You may want to consider testing the effect of thermostat and barostat on the relative energies.

Comment: @gogo, you didn't!  The problem is me.  Thanks so much for helping me to understand.  Would you happen to know where I could find more information / a proof of the internal energy being equal to the potential energy (Ep) in an NPT system?  No worries if you don't know.  I'm just interested to see how it works.  I plotted Ep.  The averages indeed look much more stable than for Ep+Ek. I notice that the results are all VERY similar for simulations run at significantly different pressures and temperatures. Don't feel obliged to respond, but I'd be very interested in anyone's opinion on this.

Comment: The internal energy should be the sum of kinetic and potential energy. The fact that the total energy is not conserved is perfectly fine as that is true of the real system interacting with the heat bath which keeps it at a constant temperature. You will want to average the internal energy of the simulation until it is converged. Then, you can do the same thing with varying compositions in your system. I know of people who do similar things for cholesterol in lipid bilayers, but I believe they usually report free energies rather internal energies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Energy in an NPT simulation is not conserved, but (once equilibrated), it will fluctuate around an average value, and that average value has meaning. That is the ensemble average for your NPT and is a valuable and useful property.

You are also correct that the internal energy is the summation of potential and kinetic contributions. To be thorough, pp. 60 of Computer Simulations Of Liquids by Allen & Tildesley (2nd edition) note

\begin{equation}
    E = \langle H\rangle = \langle \mathcal{K} \rangle + \langle \mathcal{V} \rangle
\end{equation}
where E is internal energy, H is Hamiltonian, $\mathcal{K}$ is kinetic energy and $\mathcal{V}$ is potential energy (calculated using a force-field in this case). I recommend [Allen & Tildesley](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/computer-simulation-of-liquids-9780198803201?cc=ca&lang=en&) as well as [Frenkel & Smit](https://www.amazon.ca/Understanding-Molecular-Simulation-Algorithms-Applications/dp/0122673514) if you want more information on gathering ensemble averaged properties from atomistic simulations. They are the two tomes of the field.

It is fair to compare the internal energies of two different composition simulations. It is however critical that both simulations are properly equilibrated and sampled so that $\langle \mathcal{K} \rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal{V} \rangle$ are reliable estimates.

I recommend equilibrating for several nanoseconds at the least, and sampling for several nanoseconds at the least.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a bounty until after I answered. That is a nice addition I guess :)

Comment: You can't really read the question without seeing the big blue bounty notice between the question's title and the question's body!

Comment: You can pass over it if you haven't slept very much and skip to the comments first, then scroll up the question :)

Comment: That indeed is possible :)

Comment: @CharlieCrown, thank you so much.  I didn't think I was going to get any takers for this question and got a very nice surprise just now when I checked back!